# Performing arithmetic with chars in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

How does this C/C++ code work? I understood most of it but not the part specified below:

```
c2= (c1>='a' && c1<='z') ? ('A'+c1-'a'):c1
```

Especially this part:

```
('A'+c1-'a')
```

What is this part of the code doing?

Both `c1` and `c2` have type `char`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code converts a lower case character to upper case. If the character isn't lower case then it returns the original character.

The expression `('A'+c1-'a')` does the conversion. `c1-a` will give the 0-based position of the character within the alphabet. By adding this value to `A` you will get the upper case equivilant of `c1`.

Update: if `c1` is 'b' then the expression `c1-'a'` would give 1, which is the 0-based position of 'b' in the alphabet' Adding 1 to 'A' will then give 'B'

Comment: "The expression ('A'+c1-'a') does the conversion. c1-a will give the 0-based position of the character within the alphabet. By adding this value to A you will get the upper case equivilant of c1.". Will you be more specific on this.

Comment: Specifically, ASCII `A` is 65, and ASCII `a` is 97.   If you have, for instance, `f` = 102 ASCII, then  `102-97 = 5`.  `5+65 = 70` = ASCII `F`.   This works because both upper- and lower-case letters are in alphabetical order in the ASCII encoding.

Comment: @Gopal - I've added some more info

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
('A'+c1-'a')
```

changes `c1` from lower case to upper case.

The whole statement:

```
c2= (c1>='a' && c1<='z') ? ('A'+c1-'a'):c1
```

says "if c1 is lower case, change it to upper case and assign that to c2; otherwise, just assign c1 to c2."

Comment: Thanks man you are getting me,but how <pre>('A'+c1-'a')</pre> this part is working.

Answer (score 1):

char are just integer numbers. You can add do classic operations on them.

The operation will transform (if needed) a lower case char c1 into upper case char.
But it is tricky and relies on the ASCII encoding to work and may not work with some specific local.

Instead I recommend using std::toupper, which takes into account the current local to perform the operation

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question.